# Get "name" property from variable

Tags: c#

I want an c# application in which I can modify a specified object using an int variable or with the names saved in an array(however I Prefer using an int).

Something like this:

If I have 3 buttons named `bt1`, `bt2` and `bt3`, and picture path is the path to where my pictures are ="\".

```
int btnum = 1;
bt + num .backgroundpicture=picturepath+num+".png";    
btnum +=1;
bt + num .backgroundpicture=picturepath+num+".png";
btnum +=1;
bt + num .backgroundpicture=picturepath+num+".png";
```

So that it should set the `backgroundpicture` of `bt1` to `picturepath1.png`, the `backgroundpicture` of `bt2` to `picturepath2.png` and the `backgroundpicture` of bt3 to `picturepath3.png`.

(In a realistic scenario I will use or many objects, or When I will create an unspecified amount of objects while running the code.)

Comment: Use proper tagging, what type of application is this?

Comment: Seems like a "please do my homework" question to me...

Comment: it is a c# program in visual studio 2017, the example I used isn't from the real program I plan to first use it in.

Comment: it's a 2d test program, more to try some new things and make my codes a lot  smaller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn´t rely on the names of variables as those are implementation-details that may change.

Instead of having *three* variables each referencing *one* button, use a *list* that contains *all* buttons and reference the specified one by its index:

```
var buttons = new List<Button> { btn1, btn2, btn3 };
buttons[btnNumber - 1].BackGroundImage = ...
```

Be aware that arrays and lists are zero-based, so you have to substract one. E.g. to get `btn1` you´d need `buttons[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it into a loop, something like this :

```
        int BtnNum = 1;
        int BtnNumUWant = 3;

        int X = 10;
        int Y = 10;

        string pictureName = "picturepath";

        while (BtnNum < BtnNumUWant + 1)
        {
            Button Btn = new Button();
            Btn.Name = "Btn" + BtnNum.ToString();
            Btn.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(Path.Combine(path, pictureName + BtnNum.ToString() + ".png"));
            Btn.Location = new Point(X, Y);
            Btn.Text = Btn.Name;
            Btn.Parent = this;

            BtnNum++;
            Y += 100;
        }
```

That should do what you want.

Since you want to create an "unspecified amount of objects while running the code", it's better to create your Buttons dynamically and set there position on the form (or text or whatever) in that loop.

Comment: That would create unneccesary buttons. However OP only wants to modify an *existing* one.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Since he said  "I wil create an unspecified amount of objects while running the code.", i see no point at creating buttons before code execution. It will be way more easier to manage them by code, especially if he wants to let the user set the value of `BtnNumUWant `

Answer (score 0):

An alternative if you want to truly access and affect some object based on the properties it has (dynamic) and still not be off the grid in full DLR is use Linq Expressions:

So for some object (example)

```
public class ExampleClass {
  public Button bt1 { get; set; }
  public Button bt2 { get; set; }
  .....
}
```

you could build a mutator factory from the properties and craft the assignments dynamically, as so:

```
var instance = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ExampleClass));
```

The **Where** clause is optional -- just adjusted to your situation

```
var propertiesAffected = instance.Type.GetProperties().Where(x => RegEx.IsMatch(x.Name, "[A-Za-z]+\d+")).Select(p => Expression.MakeMemberAccess(instance, p)).ToList();
```

Now, this example method is a factory method builder, define the assignment logic as a *Binary Expression*, collect these and build an Action -- then it is reusable per type given your requirements.  Also you may notice, it would be trivial to swap the ExampleClass with a Generic Argument  and type constrain to a class:

```
public Action<T> BuildAssignments<T>(Expression instance, IEnumerable<MemberExpression> propertiesAffected) where T : class {
List<Expression> operations = new List<Expression>();
foreach (var pr in propertiesAffected) {
                              int num;
                              string extract = RegEx.Match(pr.Name, "(\d+)$").Value;
                              if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(extract)) {
                                 num = Int.Parse(extract);
          // This is to wrap the calculated value as a constant value                       
          var target = Expression.Constant($"{picturepath}{num}.png");
                              // Assign the property access of BackgroundPicture from pr (so the idea of instance.bt1.BackgroundPicture) to the templated value constructed


             operations.Add(Expression.Assign(Expression.PropertyOrField(pr, "BackgroundPicture"), target));
                              }
                             }

                             return Expression.Lambda<Action<ExampleClass>>(operations, instance).Compile();
                     }
```

If for some reason you wanted to restrict to Button type only, MemberExpressions are excellent metadata handlers that are more efficient than using straight reflection/Activator code.  This allows you to dynamically collect all properties that look like bt1, bt2 or img1,img35 ...  and assign them to the templated output name as you requested, type safe and extremely performant if correctly built once, and reused for the lifecycle of the type

Ultimately the result of this call will be something like

```
var mutator = BuildAssignments<ExampleClass>(instance, propertiesAffected);
var model = new ExampleClass();
mutator(model);
// model will have properties assigned! This access is the reused item -- cache it early and save on processing
```